# Issue with fetching value from mongodb using mongoose it always returns [ ]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to learn mongoose with nodejs and created a following node function as below where in I'm receiving the email ID from the Angular application and based on the EmailId trying to find the records in MongoDb:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser= require("body-parser");
const port = 3000;
const app = express();


//setting up bodyParser middleWare
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended":true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//setting mongoose connection to local mongoDb
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/userDetails",{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true})
const db = mongoose.connection;

var userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{type:String},
    userId:{ type: String, required: true },
    password:{ type: String, required: true }
});


var users = mongoose.model('User', userSchema); 

//error handler middleWare
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
});

app.post("/login",async(req,res,next)=>{
    try {
     
      await  users.find({ email:"xyz@gmail.com"}).exec(function (err, docs) { 
    if (err){ 
        console.log(err); 
    } 
    else{ 
        console.log("First function call : ", docs); 
    } 
})
    }
    catch(err){
        next(err);
    }
})

app.listen(port,()=>{console.log("server started")});
```

The above code shows no error, but the output is always First function call :  [].My mongodb collection is as follows

```
db.User.insertMany([
   { email: "xyz@gmail.com", userId:1,password : "123@124" },
   { email: "abc@yahoo.com",userId:2,password : "123@125"},
   { email: "lmn@outlook.com", userId:3,password : "123@126"}
])


db.User.find({ email: "xyz@gmail.com"});
```

Where is that I'm going wrong ,what should be the approach to get the data?

Comment: Open your mongodb database from compass or robo3t whichever you have, check the collection and see if your email is saved exactly in db, also the search is case sensitive you need to check if you haven't save the email with an uppercase letter

Comment: Also if you are trying to get only one user document use `findOne` rather than `find`

Comment: data is in the same format as used in query @AliHussam

Answer (score 0):

Your code *should* find and print the data to the console assuming the email address you're looking for is actually in the collection. However, I want to point out a few things that don't quite make sense.

1. There is absolutely no reason to await the function call `await users.find({ email:"xyz@gmail.com"})...`. So you should change it to `users.find({ email:"xyz@gmail.com"})`
2. With that change, there is absolutely no reason for the router function to be `async`. So this is how it should look `app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {...`
3. You're not sending a response back to the caller of `/login`. So when you test, it just hangs there until you cancel your request. You should add `res.json({msg: 'ok'})` below `console.log("First function call : ", docs);`

And finally, mongoose is an awesome, promise-based library. Why not use its promise capability? It will greatly clean up your code. Here is how I would re-write your code:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    users.find({email:"xyz@gmail.com"})
        .then(docs => {
            console.log(docs);
            res.json(docs);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            next(e);
        })
})
```

Comment: why not use `async/await` and use of `try/catch` blocks to make it even more simpler. Also you still don't need to make your controller async

Comment: @AliHussam the `async` in my code was a typo. I didn't mean to leave it there. That's fixed. As for "why not `async/await`", I hate it, so I try never to use it.